# How can I convert each Pandas Data Frame row into an object including the column values as the attributes?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame including following columns "NAME", "SURNAME", "AGE" and I would like to create one object for each row, including those column values as its variables.

```
person = ConvertRow2Object(frame.iloc[0,:])
print person.NAME //outputs Gary
```

How can I do it with a generic solution to any DataFrame with any kind of column names and data types?

Comment: Does it have to be an object accessible via dot notation or can it be a dictionary accessible by a key (e.g. `person['name']`)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert the whole thing to a numpy recarray, then each record in the array is attributed:

```
people = frame.to_records()
person = people[0]
print person.NAME  # etc...
```

Using a namedtuple also seems to work:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', frame.dtypes.index.tolist())
person = Person(*frame.iloc[0,:])
print person.NAME  # etc...
```

Comment: What do you mean with `// ...`? Is that suposed to be a C style comment?

Comment: Wow, blast from the past.  No, I think I just meant a break from any other things you'd want to print.  I should just use `...`.

Answer (score 2):

This technique of creating dictionary objects and passing that as **init** argument worked for me.  This is also more generic in that you don't need to type in the key / property names

```
 #AppInfo = Class which I wanted to create instance objects for each row in df 
    def AppInfo:
        def __init__(self, attr_dict):
            if attr_dict is not None:
                for key, value in attr_dict.items():
                    setattr(self, key.replace(' ', '_'), value)
    
    # in my code this methods creates a list of AppInfo objects created from the dataframe
    def get_app_infos() -> List[AppInfo]:
       df = data.query_from_db()
       [AppInfo(a) for a in df.to_dict('r')]
```