# Convert a Pandas DataFrame into a list of objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a Pandas DataFrame into a list of objects.

This is my class:

```
class Reading:

    def __init__(self):
        self.HourOfDay: int = 0
        self.Percentage: float = 0
```

I read up on .to_dict, so I tried

```
df.to_dict(into=Reading)
```

but it returned

```
TypeError: unsupported type
```

I don't want a list of tuples, or a list of dicts, but a list of Readings. Every question I've found so far seems to be about these two scenarios. But I want my own typed objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would probably be better to initialise the class with arguments, as follows:

```
 class Reading:
   def __init__(self, h, p):
       self.HourOfDay = h 
       self.Percentage = p
```

Then, to create a list of reading, you could use this function, that takes the DataFrame as an argument:

```
 def reading_list(df:pd.DataFrame)->list:
    return list(map(lambda x:Reading(h=x[0],p=x[1]),df.values.tolist()))
```

Execution is fast, even with a large dataset.

Comment: This is insanely fast!I just switched to this from `reading_objects = reading_df.progress_apply(lambda row: Reading(*row.to_list()), axis=1)` and I got 4 fold speedup! (progress_apply is apply with tqdm progress bar, and I am still using the tqdm() function around the df.values.tolist(), so I can not be this).

Comment: I'm amazed this isn't the accepted answer. Elegant and very fast.

Answer (score 25):

Option 1: make `Reading` inherit from `collections.MutableMapping` and implement the [necessary methods](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) of that base class.  Seems like a lot of work.

Option 2: Call `Reading()` in a list comprehension:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'HourOfDay': [5, 10],
...     'Percentage': [0.25, 0.40]
... })
>>> 
>>> class Reading(object):
...     def __init__(self, HourOfDay: int = 0, Percentage: float = 0):
...         self.HourOfDay = int(HourOfDay)
...         self.Percentage = Percentage
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'{self.__class__.__name__}> (hour {self.HourOfDay}, pct. {self.Percentage})'
... 
>>> 
>>> readings = [Reading(**kwargs) for kwargs in df.to_dict(orient='records')]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> readings
[Reading> (hour 5, pct. 0.25), Reading> (hour 10, pct. 0.4)]
```

From docs:

> `into`: The collections.Mapping subclass used for all Mappings in the return value. Can be the actual class or an empty instance of the mapping type you want. If you want a collections.defaultdict, you must pass it initialized.

Comment: Your answer macthed perfectly my needs !!! Thank you very much !! Just to explain: I'm trying to convert some dataframes to "object" like formats in order to prepare them to be used as "data" for an OpenOffice template, using the [py3o.template](https://pypi.org/project/py3o.template/) library..... By the way, is there a way to automate the class "columns" innitialization ??

Comment: This should be marked as the valid answer

Comment: @linSESH I no longer use Python and was a beginner when I asked this question. Given how popular this question has become, if you can explain to me why this answer is better than the accepted one, I will happily accept this one instead

Comment: @zola25 It proposes 2 solutions, and both are better than the accepted one IMO. The second one is the same but just more elegant.

Comment: @linSESH thanks for the input, on reflection I think the most recent answer is the best

Answer (score 19):

having data frame with two column  HourOfDay and Percentage, and parameterized constructor of your class you could define a list of Object like this:

```
 class Reading:

   def __init__(self, h, p):
       self.HourOfDay = h 
       self.Percentage = p 

 listOfReading= [(Reading(row.HourOfDay,row.Percentage)) for index, row in df.iterrows() ]
```

Comment: this more generic approach worked for me  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75420677/98232