# Create objects from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object

How to create objects from pandas dataframe?

I have a class named people and i want to create objects based on column dataframe names (the column has people name too) how can be seen below:

What I have:

```
Class People:
   def__init__(self):
       pass
```

Pandas Dataframe

```
People  Age  Profession
Jorge   29   Student
Nathan  36   Enginer
```

What I want (automatically from dataframe)

```
Jorge = People()
Nathan = People()
```

Comment: Something like [Convert a Pandas DataFrame into a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53192602/15497888) or something else?

Comment: The above comment already had a link to a working solution. But what's more important is you should learn the basics of class and try coming up with your own solution, then post any error here to ask for help. Try this link https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Answer (score 0):

That's what I can propose

```py
Class People:
   def__init__(self, name, age, profession):
       self.name = name
       self.age = age
       self.profession = profession
       
def from_df_to_obj(dataframe):
    people = []
    for i in dataframe.index:
        people.append(People(dataframe["name"][i]), People(dataframe["age"][i]),  People(dataframe["profession"][i]))
    return people
```

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75420677/98232