# python code for creating class object from dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have one data frame with row entries and column names. I also have a class defined with attributes (class attribute names are different from dataframe columns).

Now the requirement is to create objects of that class per record from the dataframe and the final list of objects should be output

Class A:

```
AA, AB, AC....etc
```

dataframe:

```
A B c ...
1 2 3 ...
1 2 3 ...
```

How to avoid column names and start creating objects?

I have tried using this code:

```
Aobjs = [A(**kwargs) for kwargs in dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')]
```

Comment: Can you post actual code for generating a simplified sample dataframe, please? (`df1 = pd.DataFrame(...)`) Also, it would be more helpful for you to show us an actual DataFrame with the desired result from the simplified sample. (`result = pd.DataFrame...`) Otherwise, it will be very difficult to help you. [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will something like this work for you?:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1, 2, 3], 'two': [ 6, 5, 4]})
df
#    one  two
# 0    1    6
# 1    2    5
# 2    3    4

class Silly:
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

A = [Silly(a.one, a.two) for a in df.itertuples()]
# [<__main__.Silly object at 0x7f97b26fe7f0>, <__main__.Silly object at 0x7f97b26fe978>, <__main__.Silly object at 0x7f97b26fe4a8>]
```

My guess is that your index is not a valid kwarg.

Comment: I am planning on writing a similar Class whose attributes are values of a dataframe column. Attribute names are the column names. Seeing that you name you class Silly is making twice. Can you explain why you name your class Silly?:)

Comment: @BND, I believe he was simply using a name like `Foo` and trying to reflect the simplicity of the example.

Comment: this more generic approach worked for me  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75420677/98232